# Passing an array of pointers as a const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

What is the difference between a an array being passed as a constant versus the array values being constants?

When passing an array of pointers to a function when every value is a constant:

```
`void display(Fraction* const ar[], int size);`
```

everything works fine but when the array is a constant

```
`void display(const  Fraction* ar[], int size);`
```

the compiler gives the following error when calling the function:

```
`error C2664: 'display' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Fraction *[3]' to 'const Fraction *[]'`
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    Fraction* fArray[3];
    Fraction* fOne = new Fraction();
    Fraction* fTwo = new Fraction();
    Fraction* fThree = new Fraction();
    fOne->num = 8;
    fOne->den = 9;
    fTwo->num = 3;
    fTwo->den = 2;
    fThree->num = 1;
    fThree->den = 3;
    fArray[0] = fOne;
    fArray[1] = fTwo;
    fArray[2] = fThree;
    display(fArray, 3);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you do not intend to modify `ar` inside `display`, so you could just add `const` everywhere, i.e. `Fraction const * const ar[]` which is then a legal conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion).

Note that `const T* a[]` means `T const* a[]`, i.e. it's not the array itself that you have declared `const`; instead you have declared an array of pointers to `const` items.

Essentially, if the language provided an implicit conversion `T**` → `T const**`, then you could inadvertently attempt to change something that was originally declared `const`:

```
int const     v = 666;
int*          p;
int**         pp = &p;
int const**   ppHack = pp;    //! Happily not allowed!

*ppHack = &v;    // Now p points to the const v...
```

Comment: May I ask for an update on the link, please? I am googling in paralell, but this would help.

Comment: @DavidTóth: Done. The FAQ is now at [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/faq).